# ckeditor is not taking mathjax formula as html element

Tags: ckeditor, mathjax

I'm using `ckeditor` in my java mvc application with `mathjax` plugin for entering maths formula. On form submit I'm validating `ckeditor`; if it is blank I'm showing an error message. This part is working fine.

However, when I'm entering only a math formula without typing any text in `ckeditor` that time also it is showing enter description.

here is my code:

```
function is_questiontext_entered(type){

        var question_des_length = CKEDITOR.instances.questionContent.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText().trim();

         if(question_des_length == 0  && question_des_length=="") {
             displayErrorMessage("Enter Question Text");
             $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid red");

             return false;

         }else{

             $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid #B6B6B6"); 

             var content = CKEDITOR.instances['questionContent'].getData();
             if(content.length > 5000){
                 displayErrorMessage("Description can't be more than 5000 characters");
                 $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid red");
                // setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+type).submit(); }, 500);


             }else{

                 $("#"+type).submit();
             }

         }

}
```

this function **_questiontext_entered(type)** I'm calling on form `submit`. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_questiontext_entered(type){
    var question_des_length = CKEDITOR.instances.questionContent.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText().trim();

     if(question_des_length == 0  && question_des_length==""){
         displayErrorMessage("Enter Question Text");
         $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid red");
         return false;

     }else{
         $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid #B6B6B6"); 
         var content = CKEDITOR.instances['questionContent'].getData();
         if(content.length > 5000){
             displayErrorMessage("Description can't be more than 5000 characters");
             $("#cke_questionContent").css("border","1px solid red");
            // setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+type).submit(); }, 500);


         }else{
             $("#"+type).submit();
         }

     }
}
```

this iss is fixed used the above code